# What is the normal chmod?

Tags: file, permissions, chmod

On my web server, my file permissions are all over the place and I want to 'reset' everything back to how it originally was. I don't want any users to be able to come in and delete things off my web server! I just want them to be able to look at php pages etc.

What chmod should I use?

Comment: chmod is just about system local users however webserver uses this for check if the 'others' have permissions to read (for files) or execute (for cgi) if they havent, the webserver will return 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 42):

Here's a summary that I have gathered:
Usage: `chmod <number> <filename>`

- chmod all **files** to **644**
- chmod all .**htaccess** files to **644**
- chmod all **robots.txt** files to **644**
- chmod all **directories** to **711**
- chmod all **directories** with **directory listing** (.htaccess Options +Indexes) to **755**
- chmod all **directories** that users can **upload** files to, to **755** (ex: /uploads/).

Explanations:

- **644** means:

  - 6: the **owner** of the file/directory can **read** and **write**, but not execute. Since files are not executable, you don't need to have "x" rights here (6 means r+w. 7 means r+w+x).
  - 44: The **group** that the file/directory belongs to (see the group by using `ls -l`) and **everyone else** (the public) are able to **read** the file, but not execute or write to it (permission number 4).
- **711** means:

  - 7: the **owner** of the file/directory can **read**, **write**, and **execute**. This is needed for directories! Without "execute" when you try to list the directory you'll get permission denied.
  - 11: The **group** that the file/directory belongs to and the **public** have **execute** rights only. This is suitable for directories where you don't want other people browsing through the contents but do want to give them access to selected files further down the directory.
- **755** means:

  - 7: the **owner** of the file/directory can **read**, **write**, and **execute**.
  - 55: The **group** that the file/directory belongs to and the **public** have **read** and **execute** permissions but not write. This allows users to be able to view what files are in a directory, and be able to read those files, but not alter them.

There's also an interactive online calculator you can use to figure out what permissions to use: https://chmod-calculator.com/

Answer (score 32):

They should be as restrictive as possible, but no more.

Usually `0644` is a good choice, which gives the owner read and write rights, but everybody else only read. `0755` for directories. But, it can depend on your specific system settings.

Comment: Id 644 going to work for the PHP pages mentioned in the question, or will they need the executable bit set too? Might it depend on the web server and how it's configured?

Comment: No, unless you're doing something really crazy, you don't need the executable bit set for PHP pages. The executable bit allows binary files to be executed and PHP source code is not executable binary.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to reset everything, do this command and sort out the consequences.  Usually 644 is a good permission for files and 711 is for directories.  If you allow directory listings, then use 755.

```
$ find /var/www/html \( -type f -execdir chmod 644 {} \; \) \
                  -o \( -type d -execdir chmod 711 {} \; \)
```

If you want something less invasive, then just remove the write bits for group and "other".

```
$ chmod -R go-w /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 6):

I think `644` is standard for files and `755` for directories.

Comment: Yes that is correct for non-superuser shell users and their own directories under /home.

Answer (score 1):

If your webserver serves only webpages, without allowing access through (e.g.) anonymous FTP, then incorrect file permissions do not allow users to remove files.

If other people have access to your server through other means (e.g. SSH), then make sure that the write-bit is not set for users other than yourself. Execute:

```
find . -exec chmod go-w {} \;
```

This command will restrict the permissions of all files and directories in which it is executed.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, anonymous FTP is not allowed, but I was unsure if people could just go in and delete pages without it.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever approach you use, be sure to do some thorough testing if there is any chance that your web application relies files or dirs having certain permissions. While allowing too permissive permissions is probably bad design, this does happen sometimes, so you might break the application.