# Forbidden Error in Apache after extracting files

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

My dedicated server has Debian wheezy installed along with Apache2 php and mysql. ISPConfig3 is installed as the control panel.

After creating a site under ISPConfig and a shell user account with it I uploaded the tar file into the web directory and extracted the files.

The default ispconfig index.html file would display how ever after the extraction the index.php is not getting picked up and after deleting the default index.php i get the error message

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I tried going directly to www.domain.com/index.php and that doesnt work too.

Do I have to modify anything in apache? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the permission of the index.php, you sould be able to change them doing `chmod 644 index.php`, you could also check who is the owner of the file, is it the user running the webserver?

Comment: ok the files are set to 600 and the folders to 700. The owners and group is the shell user that is created by ispconfig3

Comment: Try changing the permission of the files to `644` and or the folders you should use `755`. You can also try to check apaches log file `/private/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Comment: Is it possible to change the permissions of all the folders to 755 and all files to 644 at one go?

Comment: You should be able to use a small shellscript to achive this, have a look at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695497/what-is-the-normal-chmod

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you the server can't read the file (or files) specified in your DirectoryIndex directive, and is trying to display a 403 (security) error document instead, which is doesn't have permission to read either.

You need to check what user your httpd daemon is running as, and make sure that user had at least read permissions to all the files in your DocumentRoot. The best way to do this is to ensure that user is the owner of the files.

On a Redhat/CentOS system, httpd runs as the user "apache"

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Comment: I think the apache user on debian is www-data?